# How to using R to do this matrix calculation?

Tags: r

I have a matrix calculation, and I need to use R to calculate.

[image: the question, Please press the link and see the photo]

Comment: I'd check out this guide to matrix algebra in R: https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html

Comment: just doing `crossprod(Z)` should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

```
z <- matrix(1:9,nrow = 3,byrow = TRUE)
z
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

t(z)%*%z
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   66   78   90
[2,]   78   93  108
[3,]   90  108  126
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
z<-matrix(seq(1:9),ncol=3,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
A=z[1,]*t(z[1,])+z[2,]*t(z[2,])+z[3,]*t(z[3,])
A
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]   66   93  126
```

Edit1: The following code works for any dimension as long as it's a square matrix:

```
colSums(t(apply(z,1,function(x)(x[1:nrow(z)]*t(x[1:nrow(z)])))))
#[1]  66  93 126
```

Edit2:

```
t(z)%*%z #the following 3 lines will all give you the same thing!
crossprod(z) 
matrix(colSums(t(apply(z,1,
function(x)(matrix(x[1:nrow(z)])%*% x[1:nrow(z)])))),ncol=nrow(z),byrow = TRUE)
  #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]   66   78   90
 #[2,]   78   93  108
 #[3,]   90  108  126
```

Comment: what about if n>3, how to do it. If n is around 3000, Please do not use the loop

Comment: @glorianrvt you can replace nrow(z) with n (make sure you first assign a number to n, like n<- 3000). Please upvote my answer if it is the correct one!

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I think apply is  a good solution for it. Though I do not know how to use it.  The outcome should be : <br/>      [,1] [,2] [,3]<br/>
[1,]   66   78   90<br/>
[2,]   78   93  108<br/>
[3,]   90  108  126<br/>
Though    colSums(t(apply(z,1,function(x)(x[1:nrow(z)]*t(x[1:nrow(z)]))))),the  answer is:<br/>[1]  66  93 126, <br/>How to solve it?

Comment: @glorianrvt you know that t(z)%*%z and crossprod(z) will give you the answer and others have left it as an answer for you! but I will leave you the edit part as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I 'd like to use apply to do.  But the outcome should be a 3 by 3 matrix, with the 1st row:66 78 90; the second row: 78 93 108;the third row:90 108 126. I use the code you suggest, the outcome is :66 93 126,  Can you help me to use apply to solve this problem?

Comment: Since apply is a common function in R.  It is faster than loop. If you can give some suggestion?

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will try it soon.

Comment: What about if x is not a n by n matrix, if it is a 2 by 5 matrix. I use the code above and get the NA element.  Can you give me some suggestion, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with matrix multiplication):

```
library(optimbase)
Z <- matrix(1:9, byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)
A <- transpose(Z[1, ]) %*% Z[1, ] + transpose(Z[2, ]) %*% Z[2, ] + transpose(Z[3, ]) %*% Z[3, ]
A # output
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   66   78   90
[2,]   78   93  108
[3,]   90  108  126
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> z <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 3, byrow=TRUE)
> z
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

> z[1,]
[1] 1 2 3

> matrix(z[1,])
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

Matrix-Multiplication (Column-Vector * Row-Vector):

```
> matrix(z[1,]) %*% z[1,] + matrix(z[2,]) %*% z[2,] + matrix(z[3,]) %*% z[3,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   66   78   90
[2,]   78   93  108
[3,]   90  108  126
```

See:
http://www.philender.com/courses/multivariate/notes/matr.html

Not the same result, when you calculate Row-Vector * Column-Vector:

```
> z[1,] %*% matrix(z[1,]) + z[2,] %*% matrix(z[2,]) + z[3,] %*% matrix(z[3,])
     [,1]
[1,]  285
```